# OKD4.7 offline installation(openstack)

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to install okd.47(4.7.0-0.okd-2021-05-22-050008) using mirror registry for offline installation(no internet), I'm able to see bootstrap node is able to pull the images from the mirror registry and when I execute "openshift-install --dir=install_dir/ wait-for bootstrap-complete --log-level=debug" command I'm able to see API is up but the master nodes are not able to pull the images from the mirror registry and I'm not able to ssh to any of the master nodes. is it possible to install OKD4.7 on a cluster without internet?
[The console of the master node can be seen like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbAgr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your loadbalancer points correctly to the bootstrap node.
Here master nodes are trying to reach the VIP that you specified to pull configurations that are generated in bootstrap node.
If your LoadBalancer is configured correctly, Try to change the algorithm to Round Robin.